# Forum navigation

Tags: nodes

I am about to launch a user forum on a site. I have installed the [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module and created a forum (only one so far, but there will be more and forum containers as well).

I would need some way to navigate through between the forums - as for now, when reading a topic, there is no way to get back to the forum listing (see [this example](http://sjukhusfysiker.se/ideer-och-forslag-till-forbattringar-till-forumet)).

When I launch the forum I will add a link in the top menu bar of course, but I feel there should be a nice way of navigating between the forum sections (without hitting the browsers back-button).

I also wonder about the paths to the topics: the path of the topic I started is

```
http://thesite.com/<name of the topic>
```

while I should prefer

```
http://thesite.com/forum/<name of forum>/<name of the topic>
```